# How to elegantly unmarshal newExchange from JSON to POJO in AggregationStrategy

Tags: json, apache-camel, unmarshalling

Is there an elegant way of unmarshaling a JSON to POJO in the Apache Camel using custom aggregation strategy?

My simple route takes a message from SQS, the message is JSON.  This message is used as input to another service, which in turn based on the message content will let me know what is the URL of a service where the original message should be posted to.

Enrich EIP with AggregationStrategy is perfect for this.  However, I cannot not figure out how to unmarshal JSON to POJO elegantly in the route.  I am able to do this via ObjectMapper but this just looks ugly.  Is there a better way of handling it?  Some magical Camel sauce that I haven's seen yet?

```
public RouteBuilder route() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("aws-sqs://" + sqsName + "?amazonSQSClient")
            .setHeader("Content-Type",simple("application/json"))
            .enrich()
            .simple("http4://localhost:8080/getUrl")
            .aggregationStrategy(new AggregationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                    String aPojoStr =  newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    RestAnswererResponse responosePojo;
                    try {
                        responosePojo = mapper.readValue(aPojoStr, RestAnswererResponse.class);
                    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing response to pojo", e);

                    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing response to pojo", e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Error parsing response to pojo", e);
                    }
                    oldExchange.getIn().setHeader("URL", responosePojo.getURL());
                    return oldExchange;
                }
            })
            .toD("http4://${header" + "URL + "}/postToAck);
        }
    };
}
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify bit more how my route needs to work:

1. SQS contains JSON message
2. Contents of the JSON message needs to be posted to service which, based on the context of the original message, determines final URL (this is context specific discovery service) of where the message should be posted. The discovery service returns only the URL of the final destination.

   ```
   {"url":"somehost:port"}
   ```
3. Once the final destination is retrieved form service discovery, the original message (as retrieved from SQS) will be posted to that final destination.

Comment: i am not sure if you should use aggregation strategy for this. You would use aggregation strategy, when you would call different endpoints and want to aggregate the results from all of these. But in your case, it is just a pipeline.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [JSON data format](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/json.adoc) to unmarshal the message, rather than messing around with `ObjectMapper`.

When using enrich I've found it useful to create a `direct` route which it calls.  I find this easier to understand, mock, test and you can give it different error handling and redelivery policies.

```
    from("aws-sqs://" + sqsName + "?amazonSQSClient")
        .setHeader("Content-Type",simple("application/json"))
        .enrich("direct:other", strategy)
        .toD("http4://${header" + "URL + "}/postToAck);

    from("direct:other")
        .to("http4://localhost:8080/getUrl")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, RestAnswererResponse.class);
```

All the strategy needs to do is extract the URL and set the header as required.

Comment: That is brilliant, just what I was looking for.  Never occurred to me to use another route.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :-)

Comment: Tried to up vote.  Seems I am too new here to have an impact.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need aggregation strategy to achieve what you want. This can be done using [jsonpath](http://camel.apache.org/jsonpath.html)

```
 from("aws-sqs://" + sqsName + "?amazonSQSClient")
            .setHeader("Content-Type",simple("application/json"))
            .setHeader("Accept", simple("application/json"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .toD("http4://localhost:8080/getUrl")
            .transform().jsonpath("url")
            .toD("http4://${body}/postToAck");
```

Considering you have a field **url** in the json response that you get from `localhost:8080/getUrl`
.

Lastly to use jsonpath you need this dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jsonpath -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
      <version>yourcamelversion</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Update :**

```
from("aws-sqs://" + sqsName + "?amazonSQSClient")
            .setHeader("Content-Type",simple("application/json"))
            .setHeader("Accept", simple("application/json"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .toD("http4://localhost:8080/getUrl")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, RestAnswererResponse.class)
            .setHeader("url", simple("${body.url}"))
            .setBody(simple("${body.originalBody}"))
            .toD("${header.url}" + "/postToAck");
```

Considering

```
public class RestAnswererResponse {
  String url;
  String originalBody;
}
```

In your `http4://localhost:8080/getUrl` endpoint, you should set the originalBody and then return. Something like this

```
class SomeController {

 @PostMapping("/getUrl")
  public RestResponse getUrl (@RequestBody String body) {
   // based on the body object decide what is the url
    return new RestResponse("url", body);// set the body it recieves as originalBody.     
}
```

For json unmarshalling, you would need

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
       <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>yourcamelversion</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that will not work.  The body I receive from SQS is the body that needs to be posted to final web service.  In your case the body will be replaced by URL.  Further I need to post the original body to the URL resolving web service, this service determines what the final destination should be based on the context of the original message.

Comment: Even that can be achieved. Checkout my Update in answer.

Comment: Love the JSON idea.  Will defintetly use that somewhere else.  However, the RestAnswererResponse does not contain the original message.